# Unclosed string error when linting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've inherited a project with the following piece of code and I can't get it to pass JSlint - does anyone know what needs to be changed please?

If i close the string on line 2 i then get Expected `'/'` and instead saw `''`.

```
$this.append(
    '<a href="' + slideLink + '"' + slideTarget + '>
        <span class="slide-time-date"></span>
        <div class="slide-overlay-text slide-overlay-text-mobile"' + slideColour + '>
            <span>' + slideOverlaytext + '</span>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-overlay-text slide-overlay-text-tablet"' + slideColour + '>
            <span>' + slideOverlaytext + '</span>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-overlay-text slide-overlay-text-desktop"' + slideColour + '>
            <span>' + slideOverlaytext + '</span>
        </div>
        <img src="' + slideImg + '" alt="' + slideTitle + '" />
    </a>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
$this.append(
            '<a href="' + slideLink + '"' + slideTarget + '>\
            <span class="slide-time-date"></span>\
            <div class="slide-overlay-text slide-overlay-text-mobile"' + slideColour + '>\
    <span>' + slideOverlaytext + '</span>\
    </div>\
    <div class="slide-overlay-text slide-overlay-text-tablet"' + slideColour + '>\
    <span>' + slideOverlaytext + '</span>\
    </div>\
    <div class="slide-overlay-text slide-overlay-text-desktop"' + slideColour + '>\
    <span>' + slideOverlaytext + '</span>\
    </div>\
    <img src="' + slideImg + '" alt="' + slideTitle + '" />\
            </a>'
    );
```

Comment: Hmm it still doesnt seem to pass jslint?